# VBA and Access Form Filter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this form in access, the purpose of it is to work as a front end of a table which can be edited through this form. Initially when it loads I display in the form data from a recordset with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM DATA
```

I want to be able to filter the data on the recordset once the form is open. I tried the following VBA code to accomplish this:

```
Private Sub Filter_Click()
    If (IsNull(Me.Find_Field) Or Me.Find_Field = "") Then
        rs.Close
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from DATA ORDER BY ID)
        rs.MoveFirst
        LoadData (True)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from DATA WHERE ID = " & Me.Find_Field)


    rs.MoveFirst
    LoadData (True) ' Function that loads the data into the form
Exit Sub
```

As you all can see, I reload the recordset with a new filtered query. Up to this point it works, the problems begin when I try to modify a record.

Originally, when the form loads the recordset data, I am able to edit the data and the edited data would show in the table (which is what I want). But after I apply my filter, my code gives me the Run-Time error '3027': Cannot Update. Databse or object is read-only.

I am pretty much using the same code over and over to reload data from the table and it never gave me a problem until I 'overwrote' the source of the recordset. Any idea how can I resolve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to use a standard Access bound form because it's simpler than what you appear to be doing.

I can change the form's RecordSource from the click event of my *cmdApplyFilter* button.

```
Private Sub cmdApplyFilter_Click()
    Dim strSql As String
    If Len(Me.txtFind_Field & vbNullString) > 0 Then
        strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblFoo WHERE id = " & _
            Me.txtFind_Field & " ORDER BY id;"
        Me.RecordSource = strSql
    End If
End Sub
```

If you're concerned someone might save the form with the filtered RecordSource, you can make the form always open with the unfiltered version.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblFoo ORDER BY id;"
    Me.RecordSource = strSql
End Sub
```